# Why use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] over $_GET['url'] in PHP after URL rewriting occurs for an MVC Router?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

### Apache (2.4.x)

If I establish a rewrite rule in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` (which is included into my main `httpd.conf`), within a `<VirturalHost>` block, like the following (as I see some example and tutorials do, not my idea):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/www/foo.com/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**1**) Do I need to specify the absolute path (seems so, as `RewriteBase` is not appropriate in this context)? It works this way, but I just wanted to know if there was something I overlooked. However, it only works this way because of a dubious suggestion (which seems unacceptable).

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted    ---> original setting: Require all denied
</Directory>
```

That seems outrageously flawed and permissive (seems). I really need to study up on the module that implements the `Require` runtime directive (`mod_access`, I think).

Is this enough (never works for me within a `<VirtualHost>` block)? Is it better to put the rewrite rules in .htaccess so that they travel with the application (instead of being coupled to the server)?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]  -->Wihout QSA, Query String Append
```

**2**) I see some people using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_GET['url']`. Is there any benefit, or advantage, to doing this?
I read some where in Stackoverflow Code Review that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will receive URL encoded values. So, I tested it and found that to be *true*.

For `http://www.foo.com/hi/there/"` ...

### $_SERVER

... you would get this in your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /hi/there%22    <---definitely URL encoded.
```

... this in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

```
[QUERY_STRING] => url=/hi/there" <---probably URL decoded?
```

this in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /hi/there"      <---probably URL decoded?
```

... and, this in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']`

```
[SCRIPT_URL] => /hi/there"       <---probably URL decoded?
```

### $_GET

```
[url] => /hi/there/"  <---probably URL decoded.
```

3) Am I wrong for wanting to use the values without `%22`? What I mean is, "Am I wrong for wanting to send that input through my filters, as opposed to the value with `%22`" For instance I use `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` (among other techniques) to validate URLs.

**Note**: *After establishing a centralized index.php, my filters on INPUT_SERVER (just 6 or 7 elements) started failing (all 6 or 7). I use `filter_input_array()` Anyone experience something similar? I can figure it out. It just started happening after implementing the rewrite rule above*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would anyone use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] over $_GET['url'] in PHP after URL rewriting occurs for an MVC Router?

Because using your approach means my app can't have a query string parameter of `url` anywhere in it, and I'll get weird, hard to diagnose behavior if I forget that. Diagnosing why `submit?url=google.com` gives me a 404 won't be much fun.

Laravel's `.htaccess` rule is just:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It'll get the route from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and parse it accordingly.

> Do I need to specify the absolute path (seems so, as RewriteBase is not appropriate in this context)?

No, and you shouldn't, so your code is portable to other servers where files may be differently located.

> 3) Am I wrong for wanting to use the values without %22?

Yes, you are. Don't use invalid unescaped characters like `"` in routes.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge "But, is that to say you would use use an invalid, escaped URL character?" Absolutely! Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Joseph%27s_College_of_Quezon_City

Comment: I am not using .htaccess. I am using a <VirtualHost> block withiin `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge OK? That doesn't change anything in this answer.

Comment: Actually, it does. For instance. Lavarel's rewrite rule will not work from within a <VirtualHost> block. But, I am testing it with a .htaccess.

Comment: "Lavarel's rewrite rule will not work from within a <VirtualHost> block." Sure it does. You just have to add `public/` to the rule because it's defaulting to the document root.

Comment: You are pretty helpful. That makes sense. I think you should get the points. And yes, you are correct, you want things like `%22` to hit FILTER_SANITIZE_URL and FILTER_VALIDATE_URL. They should get through. But, for those of us just coding for fun, you need to consider URL decoding the URL before using it to attempt route resolution. Either way, that's a fail. Use a framework if you want. I just like learning how things work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that $_GET['url'] doesn't magically exist in PHP. You need to have an entire framework setup and configured in the way you want for a value like this to exist.

In your case, you have some MVC router setup. So you should use the $_GET['url'] as it seems to be parsed by whatever framework you're using.

If you were to create a fresh PHP script with no dependencies or frameworks, $_GET['url'] will be undefined.

I prefer to parse Routes as so:

```
// Parse Request
$route = "";
$routes = [];
$url_components = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
foreach($url_components as $key => $val)
{
    if(empty($val))
    {
        if(!$key)continue;
        $route .= 'index/';
        continue;
    }

    $routes[] = $val;
    $route .= "$val/";
}

// Examine Result
$_GET['url'] = $route;
echo "Route: $_GET[url]\n";
echo "Routes Array: <pre>".var_export($routes, true)."</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I suppose that people have just been, by convention, copying what others do for URL rewriting with mod_rewrite because it's easy to find a script. But, to me, the issue isn't exploding the `REQUEST_URI`, but making sure the `REQUEST_URI` represents good data before attempting that operation. That said, thank you for responding.